# How can I estimate my starting weight when I never trained deadlift?

Tags: weightlifting, deadlifts

I do a little weight work in my home gym but am just starting out. I have never deadlifted and don't own any full size plates - only a 1" bar and a bunch of smaller-diameter plates. Bumpers are not cheap so my thought was to get a pair of plates and augment with my existing weights - then consider buying better equipment later, if I decide deadlift is something I like doing.

I have absolutely no idea what my "starting weight" should be though. For bicep curls and shoulder press I'm still only loading my 1" bar to ~20kg. The idea of buying a pair of bumpers what I could lift starting out - but would I be expecting to lift 20kg, 30, 50...?

Comment: Do you have a box gym nearby? Drop by for a free trial workout and give deadlifts a go. Might have to put up with some sales calls though... xD

Comment: It's worth noting that for deadlifts you really need either full-sized plates, or some means of elevating the bar or plates so that the bar starts around the standard height of 225mm (9 inches) off the ground. Having a bar that starts too low to the ground will be extremely awkward.

Comment: Thanks @DavidScarlett - indeed I realised this too. It's proving fairly hard to find anything suitable for a standard 1" bar so I'm gravitating towards fashioning a simple wooden 'stand' for each end. If I get into it I'd get some proper kit but getting an olympic bar and even a few proper weights is _very_ expensive.

Comment: @Mr.Boy Yep, if you have the means, building wooden blocks to raise the bar is definitely a good solution. If you want to get fancy, try googling "jerk blocks" to get some design ideas.

Comment: Learn the form without weight or even the bar. Just mimic the movement. Use a mirror or a camera to see that your back is as it should be - no arch. Once you get it correct, use 10 - 20 kg each side. See how it goes. Smaller plates are not very ideal for deadlift. Usually most people don't have problems with 10 kg plates each side on the first day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i understand but are you asking for a Deadlift Strength Standard for your weight? If yes, theres the website ExRx that provides pretty reasonable Weightlifting Performance Standards. Try for yourself if those makes sense.

https://exrx.net/Testing/WeightLifting/DeadliftStandards

Comment: I haven't heard that term but it looks like this is what I was after - it would be silly to buy 2x25Kg if I can't use them. Thanks.